# decode multiple qr code webcam based QR decoder

Tags: c#, webcam, qr-code

i am currently learning on QR code decoder. Previously, i took example from "https://zxingnet.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/Clients/EmguCVDemo/" and and rebuild it. I also added additional function to it. It is working fine as shown as below

[image]

however i soon realize that the decoder cannot decode if there is more then 1 qr code in the image during webcam video capture

[image]

i looked up at "http://zxing.org/w/docs/javadoc/com/google/zxing/multi/MultipleBarcodeReader.html" and i use the method as stated but it still cant detect qr code if there is more than 1 in the image. Would appreciate if anyone could gv some heads up or tutorial on this matter. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should change the following code within the EmguCVDemo

```
           // decode it
           var result = reader.Decode(image);
           // show result
           if (result != null)
           {
              ...
           }
```

to

```
           // decode it
           var results = reader.DecodeMultiple(image);
           // show results
           if (results != null)
           {
              // it's now an array of results
              ...
           }
```

The initialization of the reader instance should be changed from

```
reader = new BarcodeReaderImage();
```

to

```
reader = new BarcodeReaderImage() { PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat> { BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE } };
```

Comment: hai sir, thanks for the headup. i am building my project based on aforge demo. must the changes only be applied to emgu cv demo and not aforge. hope to hear from you. thank you

Comment: sorry, my mistake sir, i gave the wrong information, i build the program using "https://zxingnet.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/Clients/AForgeDemo/"

Comment: i have change the code at the decoding section.however still cannot read multiple image. i have pasted my program to here http://pastebin.com./B0VHKbGF. Can Sir have a look at it and advise. thank you.

Comment: hello sir, is there any additional reference file i need to add? i am getting error "the name barcode format does not exist in the current context"

Comment: ok, again for AForge demo:
look for the method "DecodeBarcode". Within the method there is a line "var result = reader.Decode(currentBitmapForDecoding);".
Change it to "var results = reader.DecodeMultiple(currentBitmapForDecoding);".
There is also a line "var reader = new BarcodeReader();". Change it to "var reader = new BarcodeReader { PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat> { BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE } };".
The changes are only for the original AForge demo. I have no idea if it works for your modified version. But it should.

Comment: Sir, i got an error when i start the webcam.its quite long to type so i show you the first line. "system.reflection.targetparametercountexception:parameter count mismatch. at system.window.forms.control.marshaledinvoke(control caller,Delegate method, Object[]args,Boolean synchronous)

Comment: no idea, need a full stack trace. But that exception has nothing to do with the original question here. it's better you ask a new question at this site or in the support forum of aforge, I think.

Comment: ya, true. Will try to ask around. will update Sir if have the answer to it. thanks for your help.